# Summarizing query results

Tags: sql

Looking to summary the information from this query.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber < '100' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '22%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '33%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '44%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '55%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '66%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '77%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS G,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '88%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS H
FROM 
    Database.dbo.[Transaction]
WHERE 
    EffectiveDateTime = '2012-01-03'
GROUP BY 
    DepositBatchNumber
```

I get this (image is a partial of the results):

[image: Query results]

I am looking to get this:

[image: Wanted results]

If I use `COUNT` (without the distinct option) instead of `SUM`, I get the actual count of the data in the table which I do not want.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN BatchNumber < '100' THEN 1 END) AS A,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN BatchNumber LIKE '22%' THEN 1 END) AS B,...
```

[image: Count returns bad data]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I think I've got it now: You are looking for the number of distinct DepositBatchNumbers!

```
SELECT 
    count(distinct case when BatchNumber < '100' then DepositBatchNumber end) as A,
    count(distinct case when BatchNumber like '22%' then DepositBatchNumber end) as B,
    ...
FROM Database.dbo.[Transaction]
WHERE EffectiveDateTime = '2012-01-03';
```

Comment: Thank you for the early upvote. I've changed my answer twice since then. I hope it's still worth that upvote :-)

Comment: I am looking for the number of distinct batchnumber. If I remove the group by statement I get 1's across as expected. I want to get the count of the batches in A (4), B(2), C(12)...I can see the numbers for this particular day which is helping me narrow down that fact that I have 10 years worth of data I need to summarize. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've removed the upper part of my answer. Have you tried what I am suggesting? In that final query I've removed `GROUP BY` to get one result row and I changed the expressions to `count(distinct ... DepositBatchNumber ...)`. This should get you what you want. Or if it's distinct BatchNumber  instead of distinct DepositBatchNumber you want, then replace these in the expressions.

Comment: Perfect! that did it! Thank you so much!